# Eclipse Scout Dialog form X(close) button not clickable

Tags: forms, dialog, popupwindow, eclipse-scout

I have one form wth type `Dialog`. `Modality` is set to auto. 
But the "X" button in the upper right corner cannot be clicked (not even rollover gets fired).

In Chrome I could change the z-index of the "closable" class and then it start working.

[image]

Is this a bug?If not, is there a way to get around this?

I am using Eclipse Scout Neon M5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a bug. It is fixed with this change on gerrit: [Gerrit](https://git.eclipse.org/r/#/c/67953/)

The problem occurred when a dialog is opened without any title. Then the top box was not created and the box below was moved up-> close icon is overlapped by this box.